# How can I join model without associate them in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have user model and message model, so in message model i have text, from and to, from and to is userId, so now i want to include messages in user where from is user.id and to is userId or to is user.id and fro is userId in sequelize

I did the query without associate user with message i just have my condition and have error message that says message is not associate to user! And I have tried to associate them but I can associate with just one column, i can't associate to either of from or to

Comment: If you can post some code, that will make it easier for others to understand the question better and help.